# mysql related query

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query where I need to retrieve the data from a table.

```
Table 
===================================
ID | userID | Status |   date | 
===================================
1     3333     Queued    xxxx
2     4444     Queued    yyyy
3     5555     Finished  zzzzz
5     6666     Queued    iiiii
6     7777     Queued    kkkkk
```

Now i want to retrieve the row only if the status="Queued" and  rows with status= "Queued" are more than 2 and the row with most recent ID . ie i want the answer to be ID = 6

I tried with the below query

```
select  * from t1 where status = "Queued" GROUP BY status HAVING count(status) > 2 ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a subquery for that. The problem is that the ordering is done before the grouping. Something like this should work:

```
select * from t1 where ID = (select max(id) from t1 where status = "Queued" group by status having count(status) > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should solve it:

```
select * from t1 
where id = (select max(id) from t1 where Status = 'Queued' group by Status having count(1)>2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant is also possible -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE status = 'Queued' ORDER BY ID DESC) t
GROUP BY status HAVING count(status) > 2;
```